# Spring - Extend StartupInfoLogger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging

Is it possible to extend Spring Boot `StartupInfoLogger` so that I can print out more information on startup ?

My aim is to log some application-related information, but using

```
@PostConstruct
public void contextInitialized() {
    logger.info("My information");
}
```

the information is logged before the initialization of the various beans, while I wanted to have my message logged at the very end of the bean initialization process (or as close as possible to the end) right like `StartupInfoLogger` does.

Is there a way to extend this class ? Any other suggestion to obtain the same result without involving `StartupInfoLogger` ?

Comment: What and when do you want to log?

Comment: Just some information about the application that I am launching that can be triggered by a log-analysis tool to improve automation. When I want to log is possibly after the application is started, with all the beans created.

Comment: Extending the `StartupInfoLogger` isn't going to do anything. You can create an `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` listener which will be called when the application is started and ready for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully implement what I wanted creating a new class Implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`

```
public class StartEventListener implements
        ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    Logger          logger          = Logger.getLogger(StartEventListener.class);

    // Module launched by the applications using this Listener
    final Module    module;

    public StartEventListener(Module module) {
        super();
        this.module = module;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent applicationEvent) {
        logger.warn("Module " + module.getName() + " started");
    }
}
```

I added the module information but we could add whatever info we want.

I registered a `StartEventListener` in the `@Configuration` class

```
/**
 * Listener for application start
 */
@Bean
public StartEventListener startListener() {
    return new StartEventListener(Module.PARSING);
}
```

obtaining the result of having this log row right before the end of the log at launch time:

```
2015-07-13 10:41:19,564 GMT [main] (StartEventListener.java:31) WARN  spring.StartEventListener: Module parsing started
2015-07-13 10:41:19,567 GMT [main] (StartupInfoLogger.java:56) INFO  parsing.Parsing: Started Parsing in 2.154 seconds (JVM running for 2.476)
```

Comment: Why even bother having a private no-arg constructor? I fit isn't possible to use, then simply don't add it. Saves you some code and the ugly annotation.

Comment: I added it because I have inherited parent constructor that should work, and I want to be 100% sure that I will have the module information. About ugly annotation, you are right, but I usually add it not to have warning on my IDE... I think in this case I could just strip it out

Comment: If you have specified a constructor, there is no default constructor created by the compiler. So it doesn't add anything only noise... If you have only a constructor which takes a `Module` than that is always and ever going to be the only way to construct an instance, however with your addition, using reflection you could create an invalid instance due to the availability of the private no-arg constructor. As stated remove it, and even better make the `module` field `final`.

Comment: @M.Deinum is right, there is not point in specifying the private no-arg constructor. It even allows to create an instance of `StartEventListener` using reflection and `AccessibleObject#setAccessible(boolean)`. Remove it and make the `module` field final. This way it is almost impossible to instantiate your class without passing `module`.

Comment: You are definitely right ! Thanks for the clues, constructor removed and Module set to final !